# python ipyparallel apply function in class

Tags: python, parallel-processing

Here is my snippet:

```
import ipyparallel as ipp

c = ipp.Client()

class test:
    def f(self):
       return 'hello'

    def run(self, client):
       self.c = client
       self.c[:].apply_sync(self.f)

a = test()
a.run(c)
```

And it gives me error:
`AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'wrap.<locals>.null_wrapper'`

I don't understand why.